# AS3: Create 2dimension array

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm trying to create a very simple 2d array in ActionScript 3.0

```
var arr:Array = new Array();

arr[0][0] = "Hello";
arr[0][1] = "Ali";

trace(arr[0][0]);
trace(arr[0][1]);
```

But below error has comes up :

> A term is undefined and has no properties.

Please tell me what am i doing wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to add an extra array for the first dimension:

```
arr[0] = [];
arr[0][0] = "Hello";
arr[0][1] = "Ali";
```

Comment: Thank you. It works like a charm. Please explain about this part `arr[0] = []` i can't understand it.

Comment: @HamedKamrava, at position `0`, the array now contains another array (`[]` is similar to `new Array()`). So you have an array of arrays.

Comment: A multidimensional array is an array of arrays, a nested structure. You need to create intermittent layer objects to make a multidimensional array.

Comment: Take a look at : "ActionScript 3 fundamentals: Arrays" on Adobe website
http://www.adobe.com/devnet/actionscript/learning/as3-fundamentals/arrays.html
Hope it will be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

This line:

```
 var arr:Array = new Array([3], [3]);
```

Is creating an array containing two arrays, each of which has one element containing the number 3. That means that when you get to the third iteration multiArr[i] is undefined. This is clearly a misunderstanding of how to define arrays in AS31

SO YOU JUST REFER THIS LINK

[Problem with 2d Array in AS3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7146563/problem-with-2d-array-in-as3?rq=1)